# How can I connect Alexa with recast.ai chatbot using powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, sap-conversational-ai

I have build a chatbot with recast.ai and now want to connect it with alexa, so that the requests from alexa are integrated in recast.ai. Therefore I want to use 
"REQUEST_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxx npm start" in windows powershell in order to send the requests to my server.

Then, I get the following error message:

[image]

Do you know how I can solve this problem instead?

Thank you very much for answering

Comment: Please don't post error messages as image attachments. One can't search for their contents and red-on-blue is hard to read.

Comment: The error message is very clear with what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the command

```
REQUEST_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxx npm start
```

is being parsed by Powershell as

```
Execute REQUEST_TOKEN=xxx and pass two parameters, (npm, start), to it
```

The error message tells that as far as Powershell knows, `REQUEST_TOKEN=xxx` is neither a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Thus you'll get an error.

I have no knowledge about Recast.ai, so I can't help you about how to use the token properly.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa is now supported as a channel directly from the bot connector it should be really easy to connect a bot via the bot connector for interface to Alexa